# Ngrok not working after add the auth token and doing all the steps -blackeye

Tags: ngrok, phishing

Ngrok not working in blackeye :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y54Yy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg0Ty.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as screenshots. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Hacking, phishing, etc is not allowed on the ngrok platform. Even "ethical hacking" is against the TOS.

As soon as you are detected or reported, your account will be blocked.

*- an ngrok employee*